# QFile write a WAV header writes only 4 byte data

Tags: qt, wav, qfile

I'm writing a WAV recorder, using QFile as backbone. However, when I fill my Wav struct, and try to write it to my QFile it writes only "RIFF", I viewed it with unix's `od -cb 1.wav`. Here is the samle code:

wavwriter.cpp

```
   Wav::Wav(const char *fname, QFile* parent)
    : QFile(fname, parent),
      m_fname(fname)
{
    setFileName(fname);
    bool res = this->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    if (res) {
        std::cout << "File opened for RW\n";
    }
}

Wav::~Wav()
{
}

void Wav::writeHeader(const WavHdr* hdr)
{
    write((char*)hdr);
    flush();
}

void Wav::appendData(const QByteArray &data)
{
    m_data.append(data);
}

QByteArray Wav::getWavData()
{
    return m_data;
}
```

And the usage is as follows:

```
    WavHdr hdr;
    hdr.bits_per_sample = 8;
    hdr.riff[0] = 'R';
    hdr.riff[1] = 'I';
    hdr.riff[2] = 'F';
    hdr.riff[3] = 'F';
    hdr.sample_rate = 8;
    hdr.fmt[0] = 'f';
    hdr.fmt[1] = 'm';
    hdr.fmt[2] = 't';
    m_wavs[i]->writeHeader(&hdr);
```

The WavHdr has the following setup:

```
    struct WavHdr
{
    char riff[4];
    qint32 file_size;
    char wave[4];
    char fmt[4];
    char len[3];
    qint16 type;
    quint16 format;
    qint32 sample_rate;
    qint32 sr_bs_channs;
    quint8 bits_per_sample;
    char data[4];
    qint32 fsize;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can't dump `WavHdr` to disk directly.

   The way you use the `write` method only makes sense for zero-terminated strings. It will stop writing at the first zero-valued byte. A `WavHdr` is **not** a null-terminated string.

   You cannot assume that the struct has any particular representation in memory. The compiler is free to arrange that structure the way it sees fit. Not only it can pad and align the members arbitrarily, it can also rearrange them. So that's a non-portable anti-pattern: it may happen to work on some compilers, on others it will be thoroughly broken.
2. Your `WavHdr` is wrong.

   See [here](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) for reference. I've included a correct header structure below.
3. You probably wish to use a `QSaveFile`.

   When saving files, you usually intend the file writing to be atomic: either it succeeds and you get a complete, valid `WAV` file, or it fails and nothing changes on disk (e.g. an existing file is not overwritten and corrupted). That's what `QSaveFile` is designed for.
4. You probably want your wave class to use an I/O device, but not be one.

   I/O can be done with just an instance of a `QIODevice*`: you'll then be able to easily write the data to in-memory buffers, files, network sockets, etc. The user of your class should be free to choose what particular device to use.

Instead, use `QDataStream` to write the header in a portable way:

```
struct WavHdr
{
   constexpr static quint32 k_riff_id = 0x46464952;
   constexpr static quint32 k_wave_format = 0x45564157;
   constexpr static quint32 k_fmt_id = 0x20746d66;
   constexpr static quint32 k_data_id = 0x61746164;
   // RIFF
   quint32 chunk_id = k_riff_id;
   quint32 chunk_size;
   quint32 chunk_format = k_wave_format;
   // fmt
   quint32 fmt_id = k_fmt_id;
   quint32 fmt_size;
   quint16 audio_format;
   quint16 num_channels;
   quint32 sample_rate;
   quint32 byte_rate;
   quint16 block_align;
   quint16 bits_per_sample;
   // data
   quint32 data_id = k_data_id;
   quint32 data_size;
};

bool write(QIODevice * dev, const WavHdr & h) {
  QDataStream s{dev};
  s.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian); // for RIFF
  s << h.chunk_id << h.chunk_size
    << h.chunk_format;
  s << h.fmt_id << h.fmt_size
    << h.audio_format
    << h.num_channels
    << h.sample_rate
    << h.byte_rate
    << h.block_align
    << h.bits_per_sample;
  s << h.data_id << h.data_size;
  return s.status() == QDataStream::Ok;
}
```

Comment: 1st is wrong. You can do `write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(hdr), sizeof(*hdr));` as file is open as binary. But the structure must be packed to do it correctly, and little-endianness must be provided.

Comment: @ilotXXI "Packing" the structure correctly and making it little endian is not portable. C/C++ `struct` isn't designed to give any sort of a binary layout that you can count on. You can do plenty of hacks, but that doesn't mean they are correct or reasonable.